# Dynamics GP Web Service -- Returning list of sales order based on specific criteria

Tags: asp.net, web-services, dynamics-gp

For a web application, I need to get  a list or collection of all **SalesOrders** that meet the folowing criteria:

- Have a **WarehouseKey.ID** equal to "test", "lucmo" or "Inno"
- Have **Lines** that have a **QuantityToBackorder** greater than 0
- Have **Lines** that have a  **RequestedShipDate** greater than current day.

I've succesfully used these two methods to retrieve documents, but I can't figure out how return only the ones that meet above criteria.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508527.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508537.aspx

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: your query isn't possible through the GP Web Services. Even your warehouse key isn't an accepted criteria for GetSalesOrderList. To do what you want, you'll need to drop to eConnect or direct table access. eConnect has come a long way in .Net if you use the Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect and Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization libraries (which I highly recommend). Even in eConnect, you're stuck with querying based on the document header rather than line item values, though, so direct table access may be the only way you're going to make it work.

In eConnect, the key piece you'll need is generating a valid RQeConnectOutType. Note the "ForList = 1" part. [That's important.](http://theruntime.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2010/08/19/Banishing-Shadows-in-eConnect.aspx) Since I've done something similar, here's what it might start out as (you'd need to experiment with the capabilities of the WhereClause, I've never done more than a straightforward equal):

```
private RQeConnectOutType getRequest(string warehouseId)
{
    eConnectOut outDoc = new eConnectOut()
    {
        DOCTYPE = "Sales_Transaction",
        OUTPUTTYPE = 1,
        FORLIST = 1,
        INDEX1FROM = "A001",
        INDEX1TO = "Z001",
        WhereClause = string.Format("WarehouseId = '{0}'", warehouseId)
    };
    RQeConnectOutType outType = new RQeConnectOutType()
    {
        eConnectOut = outDoc
    };
    return outType;
}
```

If you have to drop to direct table access, I recommend going through one of the built-in views. In this case, it looks like ReqSOLineView has the fields you need (LOCNCODE for the warehouseIds, QTYBAOR for backordered quantity, and ReqShipDate for requested ship date). Pull the SOPNUMBE and use them in a call to GetSalesOrderByKey.

And yes, hybrid solutions kinda suck rocks, but I've found you really have to adapt if you're going to use GP Web Services for anything with any complexity to it. Personally, I isolate my libraries by access type and then use libraries specific to whatever process I'm using to coordinate them. So I have Integration.GPWebServices, Integration.eConnect, and Integration.Data libraries that I use practically everywhere and then my individual process libraries coordinate on top of those.

Comment: Also, eConnect may need to use LOCNCODE instead of WarehouseId. I haven't had to use either, yet, so I can't say for certain...

Comment: Thanks, Jacob. This gives me something to look into. Another question, what if I wanted to return ALL SalesOrders using GetSalesOrderList? What criteria would I use since SalesOrderCriteria is mandatory for the call?

Comment: Just don't add criteria to any of the properties of SalesOrderCriteria. Though really, you probably want to include TransactionState and just pull unposted Sales Orders. Or use the Date criteria to pull orders in the last few months, maybe.